# How can I call a method from an other class/component in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, components, preact

I am still a rookie in frontend. I have 2 **NON RELATED** (no parent/child relation) classes:

```
search.js
Class Search{
   method,
   state
}

view.js
Class view{
     content
}
```

I am trying to:

- call a **search.js** method from **view.js**.
- change state value of **search.js** from **view.js**

**Additional info:**

- I have already tried using [helper functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23485775/how-can-i-call-a-method-from-the-driver-class). It was not the desired solution.
- I am using Preact which is a leightweight version of React.

Thanks!

Code:

```
export default class Search extends Component {
    constructor() {
        this.state = {
            input: ""
        };
    }

    search(input) {
        this.setState({ input: input });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the classes are unrelated, then there are only three ways you can use a class's methods outside the class (or, really, inside it):

1. If it's a `static` method, call it directly:

   ```
   Search.theStaticMethod()
   ```
2. If it's a prototype or instance method, the usual thing is to create an instance and then call the method on that instance:

   ```
   const s = new Search(/*...*/);
   s.prototypeOrInstanceMethod();
   ```
3. If it's a prototype method, you *can* call it without creating an instance, but it's **extremely likely to be incorrect** to do so:

   ```
   // ALMOST CERTAINLY NOT THE RIGHT THING
   Search.prototype.prototypeMethod();
   ```

   There's a variation on that where you apply the method to an object, even though that object wasn't created via `new Search`:

   ```
   // ALMOST CERTAINLY NOT THE RIGHT THING
   const obj = {};
   Search.prototype.prototypeMethod.call(obj);
   ```

   The method will get the object as `this`, and may or may not work correctly depending on how it's written.

Comment: Thank you so much! Method #2 was the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need an instance of class as answered already.

```
const myInstance = new Search();
```

You can export this instance instead of exporting class.

```
export {myInstance};
```

In view.js you need to import it

```
import {myInstance} from './relative-path';
```

And then you call method

```
myInstance.search('someInput');
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking **more react** than vanilla js ... probably already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51661103/6124657) or even (primitively) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50466217/6124657)

> I have 2 NON RELATED (no parent/child relation) classes:

Both in the same screen/view/app/component tree? Then indirectly but still related.

> I am trying to:
>
> - call a search.js method from view.js.
> - change state value of search.js from view.js

There are a few ways to manage common state (values or methods):

- state in common parent ( [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) ), even top `<App />` component
- using refs
- using context api
- redux
- apollo client

Using Preact - then search for some tiny global state management, f.e. [statext](https://github.com/eldh/statext) or [unstated](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated)